# Named Entity Recognition using Python spaCy

Tags: python, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I want to code a Named Entity Recognition system using Python `spaCy` package. However, I couldn't install my local language inside `spaCy` package. Is there anyone who can tell me how to install or otherwise use my local language?

I tried:

```
python -m spacy download xx_ent_wiki_sm
```

I appreciate the help!

Comment: What is your local langauge?

Comment: Amharic language which is  spoken in Ethiopia.

Comment: Is you language model already packaged or just saved in a separate folder?

Answer (score 3):

`spaCy` supports a limited amount of languages with standalone models. If you language is one of:

> **Chinese, Danish, Dutch, English, French, German, Greek, Italian, Japanese, Lithuanian, Norwegian, Bokmål, Polish, Portuguese, Romanian or Spanish**

Then you can load the model by first installing it through a similar command that you have posted, for example:

```
# Lithuanian language
python -m spacy download lt_core_news_sm

# Japanese language
python -m spacy download ja_core_news_sm
```

You would have to run this command in your command line (terminal). After the model is finished downloading and is linked, you can import it like this:

```
import spacy

# Loading the Japanese language model.
nlp = spacy.load("ja_core_news_sm")
```

`spaCy` also support a **multi-language model** that you can try to use if your language is not supported with it's own model. For that, you can do (looks like you already tried to install it in your provided command):

```
# In command line
python -m spacy download xx_ent_wiki_sm

# In Python
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("xx_ent_wiki_sm")
```

However, do not expect state-of-the-art results from using the multi-language model as it is not specifically trained on a single language like the other models are.

Comment: thank you for ur  comment...but how to install my own language model/package to python  like installing  spacy package.

Comment: The most last comment here was in 2020. Do you know if the multi-language model has evolved now? has it become more reliable? I can already notice from SpaCy site that the number of supported languages became 88.. it's apparently not just limited in a limited set of languages. I'll be happy to hear from you. Thanks!